# Regex that allow for numbers with leading zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirement is that I should pass 4 or more "digits" and fail the rest. The regex I used is:

```
var test = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4,100}$/);
```

However, numbers with leading zeros like 0001 or 0123 fail. How can I modify the regex to allow for numbers with leading zeros while sticking to my requirement.
Thanks!

Comment: The regex succeeds: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vR4bA2/1) although it is adviseable to use a `^` in front.

Comment: It should pass zeros infront

Comment: Your regex does allow leading zeros.

Comment: What you have is working: https://jsfiddle.net/n0cpd4aL/1/

Comment: Just to clarify the confusion. The reason why the regex didn't work is because I was passing it in as an int and not as a string. If you pass this expression any number with leading zeros as an int it will fail. So to pass a number with leading zeros you have to pass the digits in a string format. I would refer you to mark's answer below.

Comment: Not true. A number like 01234 will pass. The leading zeros are simply ignored if you don't use quotes. If the rest of the numbers (1234) would pass then the expression will pass.

Comment: yes true! But I want to account for the zeros as well so that a number like 0001 will also pass :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have quotes around the number you're testing. The syntax is:

```
RegExpObject.test(string)
```

var test = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4,100}$/);

This returns false because it is interpreted as the number 9:

```
test.test(000009);
```

The leading zeros are ignored.

This returns true because the whole string is considered:

```
test.test('000009');
```

Comment: Omg.. passing it as a string actually works. lol. I thought for sure it would fail cause its a string and we are checking for numbers. I guess it works cause we are not specifying digits in the expression. Anyways Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the follwoing regex to find numbers that do not start with zeros:

```
\b[1-9]\d{3,}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iT4yP1/1)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Mark already answered the question. Its works when you pass it in as a string. But special thanks for pointing out to lose the 100 digit limit. :)